# Calling Entity Framework function import from code

Tags: entity-framework

So I have a stored procedure called Spr_EventLogCreate defined in my database.  I have created a function import in my data model called LogEvent with no return type, and I can see this function in the Model Browser tree at

MyModel.edmx > MyModel > EntityContainer > Function Imports > LogEvent.

I thought I should then be able to call the function in my code as follows:

```
var context = new MyModelEntities();
context.LogEvent(...);
```

But the LogEvent() method is not present.

I must be being really stupid here, but how do I call my imported function?

Using VS 2008 and EF 3.5.

Comment: Search the codegen file for `LogEvent`. Do you see it? It should be there.

Comment: Yeah I tried that too, but there are no references to that string at all.

I just tried deleting and re-adding the function import as well, and again searched the whole solution for the string "LogEvent", but I still can't see it...

Oh, and hello Craig - you used to help me a lot on the Interbase forums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to generate the code calling the function not retuning a result set from design time in default Microsoft designer. You can write code calling it manually in the partial definition of your context class.
Here is an example:

```
        public void EmpDelete (global::System.Nullable PEMPNO, global::System.Nullable PDEPTNO)
        {
            if (this.Connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
              this.Connection.Open();
            System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommand command = new System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommand();
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandText = @"DataSourceModel1Entities.EmpDelete";
            command.Connection = (System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection)this.Connection;
            EntityParameter PEMPNOParameter = new EntityParameter("PEMPNO", System.Data.DbType.Decimal);
            if (PEMPNO.HasValue)
                PEMPNOParameter.Value = PEMPNO;
            command.Parameters.Add(PEMPNOParameter);
            EntityParameter PDEPTNOParameter = new EntityParameter("PDEPTNO", System.Data.DbType.Decimal);
            if (PDEPTNO.HasValue)
                PDEPTNOParameter.Value = PDEPTNO;
            command.Parameters.Add(PDEPTNOParameter);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Comment: Hm thanks... any idea why it is implemented this way?  Why can it not generate the calling code automatically?

Comment: It is a problem of VS 2008. The code is generated in VS 2010 RC.

Comment: @Devart I would say its a problem with EF 1.0. Im using VS2010 with EF 1.0 and having the same problem.